# How to create a silverlight page with controls in another language?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, microsoft-translator

I have created a silverlight page in which i have different controls (all in english). Now i want this to be in Hindi (or any other language).

I know we have Bing Translator avalible to trasnlate. I have also used BING translator in various blogs which can translate in any language we want.

I want to do similar stuff in my silverlight page also. One approach i see is that all controls does have "Content" property. So any translation button which reloads page with all Content property changed to another language ?

Please suggest how can i change language of my page ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should try to start here: [MSDN: Localizing Silverlight-based Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838238%28VS.95%29.aspx) and here: [jeff prosise's blog - Dynamic Localization in Silverlight](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2010/06/21/dynamic-localization-in-silverlight.aspx) is a nice quick example.